# storing values from a spreadsheet in an object with google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I am trying to write a program that will take entries from a spreadsheet and store data taken from the cells in each row as an object, such that the entries can be used later.

While I have had little trouble getting the program to find data in the document, I have been having trouble making the program store the data that it retrieves in a new object so that said data can be used later in the program.

when I try to have the program print what it has taken from the spreadsheet on a document, it just returns undefined   (note: for the purposes of trying to create a working prototype of this project. I am only dealing with one entry currently. I am also very new to Google script,. so apologies if I have made any terrible errors).

```
       var one =[];

var two =[];

var three =[];

var four =[];

var five =[];   

var sortData = function(startRow, endRow){
  //var sortedSheet = SpreadshetApp.create("sorted");

  function entry(firstname, lastname, firstchoice, secondchoice, thirdchoice){
    this.firstName = firstname;
    this.lastName = lastname;
    this.firstChoice = firstchoice;
    this.secondChoice = secondchoice;
    this.thirdChoice = thirdchoice;
  };

  for(x = startRow;x <= endRow;x++){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var name1 = sheet.getRange("B"+x.toFixed(0)).getValue();
    var name2 = sheet.getRange("C"+x.toFixed(0)).getValue();
    var choice1 = sheet.getRange("D"+x.toFixed(0)).getValue();
    var choice2 = sheet.getRange("E"+x.toFixed(0)).getValue();
    var choice3 = sheet.getRange("F"+x.toFixed(0)).getValue();
    var entries = DocumentApp.create("this code works");
    var x = new entry(name1, name2, choice1, choice2, choice3);

    switch(x.firstChoice.toFixed(1)){
      case "1.0":
        one[one.length] = this;
        entries.getBody().appendParagraph(one[0].firstChoice);
        break;
      case "2.0":
        two[two.length] = this;
        entries.getBody().appendParagraph(two[0].firstChoice);
        break;
      case "3.0":
        three[three.length] = this;
        entries.getBody().appendParagraph(three[0].firstChoice);
        break;
      case "4.0":
        four[four.length] = this;
        entries.getBody().appendParagraph(four[0].firstChoice);
        break;
      case "5.0":
        five[five.length] = this;
        entries.getBody().appendParagraph(five[0].firstChoice);
        break;      
      default:
        Logger.log("this code is not working");

    }

      }
}

function onOpen(){
var current = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1uHWBHeqnl18pDDxbSJj2_WyTXxaT96UfRg4oZEF7uHc");

Logger.log(current.getName());

SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(current);

sortData(2,2);
}
```

Anything that helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getValsFromSheet(startRow, endRow) {
if(!startRow){ startRow = 1}
if(!endRow){ endRow = 2}

  var as = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = as.getActiveSheet();
  var numOfRows = endRow - startRow+1;
  var rowData = sheet.getRange(startRow,1,numOfRows,2).getValues();
  var rowDataAsString = JSON.stringify(rowData);

  var properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  properties.setProperty("storedValue", rowDataAsString);
}

function getValsFromProps(){
  var properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var storedValueString = properties.getProperty("storedValue");
  var storedValue = JSON.parse(storedValueString);
  Logger.log(storedValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
var x = new entry(name1, name2, choice1, choice2, choice3);
```

Is creating an object named "x", but nothing is getting put into the object.

The `entry` function is not returning anything.  You need a return statement to return the object into "x".

Note the return statement:

```
function entry(firstname, lastname, firstchoice, secondchoice, thirdchoice) {
  Logger.log('firstchoice: ' + firstchoice);

  this.firstName = firstname;
  this.lastName = lastname;
  this.firstChoice = firstchoice;

  Logger.log('theObject.firstChoice: ' + this.firstChoice);

  this.secondChoice = secondchoice;
  this.thirdChoice = thirdchoice;

  return this;
};
```